# How can I get travel time between two location on google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I can get distance between two location using direction api and this method

My code is for get distance:

```
 @Override
  public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        if (direction.isOK()) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = 
  direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();

 myMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(getActivity(), 
 directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
 LatLng(origin.latitude, origin.longitude)).title("Pickup 
 Location").snippet(pickup_address).
 icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker
 (BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
  myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
 LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude))
.title("Drop Location").snippet(drop_address).icon
(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin, 
10));

  calculateDistance(Double.valueOf(direction.getRouteList()
 .get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDistance().getValue()) / 1000);
```

How can I get travel time using direction api in google map in android ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [Distance Matrix Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) from google. Using this method allows you to set the mode of transportation for the most accurate travel time.

```
try{
        val context = GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(Constants.GOOGLE_API_KEY)
                .build()

        val req = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context)
        val origin = LatLng(fromlocation.getLatitude(), fromlocation.getLongitude())
        val destination = LatLng(tolocation.getLatitude(), tolocation.getLongitude())

        val trix = req.origins(origin)
                .destinations(destination)
                .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .await()

        eta = trix.rows[0].elements[0].duration.humanReadable

    }catch (ex:Exception){
        Log.e("ETA", ex.message)
    }
```

Comment: can you give me any example of this api ? i can try it but i can't able to get travel time

Answer (score 1):

You can use directions api to find the distance between the origin and destination

```
 public String getDistance(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2) {
    final String[] parsedDistance = new String[1];
    final String[] response = new String[1];
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");
                Log.v("urldirection", url.toString());
                final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                response[0] = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response[0]);
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(1);
                JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("duration");
                parsedDistance[0] = distance.getString("text");

            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.v("DistanceGoogleAPi", "Interrupted!" + e);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return parsedDistance[0];
}
```

calling this method will return the distance.Change the query parameters in the url as per your requirement.

Comment: get error E/e: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)

Comment: enable directions in your google cloud platform and your key to the url

Comment: i change url and also enable direction api but its stll geting error index 0 out of range

Comment: did you add your api key as one of the parameter in url? something like this "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving&key=YOUR_KEY"

Comment: {
  "geocoded_waypoints": [
    {
      
    },
    {
      
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    
  ],
  "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}

Comment: i get this response

Comment: can you please share your url

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=22.283929,70.76554279999999&destination=72.83106070000001,21.170240099999997&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving&key=key

Comment: i also add my key value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180507/discussion-between-nagendra-hari-karthick-and-darshi).