# How to I add estimated travel time and route alternatives on google map android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add estimated travel time on different routes on google map android like this image [google map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTBis.png). How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52439462/9346054

Comment: Another link that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176753/how-implements-the-google-distance-matrix-api-at-android-studio